# DTD definition error

Tags: xml, dtd

It will get a error to define a dtd as follow:

```
<!ELEMENT line (property*)>
<!ATTLIST line showType (1|?|+|*) "1" >
```

The error:

```
The name token is required in the enumerated type list for the "showType" attribute declaration.
```

It seems the value can't be special characters,such as "?","+","*". To change the characters to Latin-1 characters, like "& #42;"(add a blank before '#') , get the same error.

How to resolve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess, you will somehow have to escape the special chars (which is not the same as using the ampersand quoting). Unfortunately, my SGML is not good enough to know how to do this. Have you used quotes (like `"`) already?

Comment: I edit the DTD in Eclipse which will auto validate the file when change occurs.

Comment: Using Quote will get the same error too.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible, as all the enumerated values you specify must be conformant Nmtokens as specified by the XML Recommendation. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#d0e3200.

The BNF for Nmtokens can be seen at http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#d0e804.